# Specifing a jQuery version for Meteor twbs:bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

After installing Meteor via Chocolatey on windows 10, and `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` This Meteor app gives a barowser error

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

So which version am I running now?

`meteor list` did not produce any jquery related lines.

`./meteor/versions` file has a line saying `"jquery@1.11.11"`

But didn't `meteor create` already install a jQuery as per the [web site](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery)?  "This package is automatically included in every new Meteor app by meteor create."

DO I need to run `meteor add jquery`? but I remember doing that already at least once. and `"jquery": "^3.5.1"` is under dependencies in packages.json and package-lock.json

The command: `meteor show jquery` shows package: `jquery@3.0.0`

Please help untangle this. Thanks

**Solved:**

```
meteor remove twbs:bootstrap
npm install bootstrap
```

Added `"popper.js":"^1.16.0"` to dependencies in `package.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the **Meteor package version** `jquery@3.0.0` and the **npm version** `"jquery": "^3.5.1".

The Meteor package `jquery@3.0.0` allows to override deprecated jQuery versions (for example delivered as direct dependency of an old Meteor package) with the jQuery version, installed via npm.

> `./meteor/versions` file has a line saying `"jquery@1.11.11"`

Note, that just adding `jquery@3.0.0` sometimes fails (when packages require direct dependencies). Then you have to change in your `.meteor/packages` the entry `jquery@3.0.0` to `jquery@3.0.0!`

However, this may still cause the mentioned error, because your jQuery will be a version > 3 (because your project will then use the npm jQuery 3.5.1).

**What are your options then to resolve the error:**

- a) Install npm `jquery` > 1 and < 3
- b) Install the latest jQuery and use Bootstrap 4 via npm

**option a**

The first option would basically require you to run `meteor npm install --save jquery@2.2.4` to get the latest jQuery < 3.

This could be a fast solution, if your app will be used internally (for example in a corporate intranet or smth.) but would be a big problem if out in the wild. There are [plenty of vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery) that have been detected since `3.5.1` and you should think about, whether this will be an issue or not.

**option b**

The better way is to also use the latest bootstrap an jQuery from the beginning and use their npm packages. It is a bit more of work than just adding `twbs:bootstrap` but it gives you the flexibility and maintainability that you need:

1. install the latest npm packages

```sh
$ meteor remove twbs:botstrap
$ meteor npm install --save jquery@latest bootstrap popper.js
```

2. edit the Meteor jquery package

Open `.meteor/packages` in your editor of choice and change:

`jquery@3.0.0` to `jquery@3.0.0!`

3. import the packages

In your startup routine, for example in `client/main.js` you do the following:

```js
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' // default theme
import popper from 'popper.js'

global.Popper = global.Popper || popper
```

3. (optional) import a custom theme

If you want to apply your own theme, your may also install the [scss toolchain](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss):

```sh
$ meteor remove standard-minifier-css
$ meteor add fourseven:scss seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

and then import your custom theme instead of the standard css:

```js
import 'bootstrap'
import popper from 'popper.js'
import './theme.scss'

global.Popper = global.Popper || popper
```

to apply your own theme, you need to have `theme.scss` to follow the structure below:

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "{}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "{}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "{}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/buttons";
/* these are just examples, if your theme overrides more you need to import the respective files */

/* -------begin customization-------- */

/* here your custom theme variables, colors etc. */

/* ------- end customization -------- */

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "{}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

I know this might be too much of an answer but in the long run I highly suggest you to omit the deprecated BS3 and go for a more flexible strategy, as shown in option b here.